# Damage not applied to the player

Tags: unity, c#, first-person-shooter

I created a turret firing missile to player but for some reason the damage is not applied to the player, and the missile is not firing correctly: collision is not triggered. Here's my code. I cannot understand what could possibly be the reason.

```
public class DamagePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject player;
    private PlayerHealth _playerHealth;

    void Start()
    {
        if (player != null)
        {
            _playerHealth = player.transform.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        }
        else
        {
            print("player Gameobject not found");
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        print("collision trigger works");
        if(other.transform.tag == "Rocket")
        {
            _playerHealth.playerHealth = _playerHealth.playerHealth - 10;
            print(_playerHealth.playerHealth);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public GameObject rocketPrefab;
public GameObject spawnPoint;
private bool _firing;
public float fireRate;
public bool turretActive = true;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (turretActive)
    {
        if (!_firing)
        {
            FireTheRocket();
            StartCoroutine(RateOfFire());
        }
    }
}

void FireTheRocket()
{
    Instantiate(rocketPrefab, spawnPoint.transform.TransformPoint(0, 0, 0), spawnPoint.transform.rotation);
}

IEnumerator RateOfFire()
{
    _firing = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
    _firing = false;
}
```

Comment: Usual things to check for collision bugs: do both objects involved have a (3D) collider component attached? Is the "Trigger" flag checked for either of them? Does at least one of those objects have a dynamic Rigidbody component attached (not kinematic/static)? Are the two objects on physics layers that process collisions with one another?

Comment: Regarding the rigidbody component, I added the component to the rocket but for some reason it wouldn't fire correctly

Comment: How did the behaviour you observed differ from what you would deem "correct"? Remember we can't see your screen, so any symptoms of the problem we might need to know in order to help you solve it, you need to tell us or show us explicitly.

Comment: The start to make sure that the player can be damaged would be to just place the rocket in the scene and check if it damagaes the player. Once that works, you would next figure out how to get the turret working. One error at a time